# jQuery File Uploader Plugin and Symfony 2

Tags: php, jquery, symfony, upload

I want to use this plugin in my symfony 2 project:

https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Basic-plugin

I followed all the steps in the documentation. But it keeps saying that this path is not found :

```
error:
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

path:
http://localhost/vdvinfra/web/js/file-uploader/server/php/
```

My code in the twig file :

```
  <input id="fileupload" type="file" name="files[]" data-url="{{asset('js/file-uploader/server/php/')}}" multiple>
```

my js :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function () {
    $('#fileupload').fileupload({
      /* ... */
      progressall: function (e, data) {
        var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
        $('#progress .bar').css(
          'width',
          progress + '%'
        );
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think `web/` should be part of your path (Unless `http://localhost/vdvinfra/web/` is the base path of your application). Could you print the output of `{{asset('js/file-uploader/server/php/')}}`?

Also, when you want Symfony to handle your uploads, I recommend you take a look at the [OneupUploaderBundle](https://github.com/1up-lab/OneupUploaderBundle) bundle. It has [step by step](https://github.com/1up-lab/OneupUploaderBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/frontend_blueimp.md) instructions about how to set up Symfony with the jQuery File Uploader Plugin.